# Can I change my own password in Active Directory using Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, passwords, change-password

I am trying to **change password for my own account in AD using powershell**. My account is just a regular account (no domain admin rights)

I tried net user, dsquery and powershell cmdlets, but all of them errors out "Access is denied". I think all of those requires admin rights.

Is there a way to change my own password using powershell or cmd ?

Why I am doing that?
We have 8 different AD domains and I have an account in each. With different password expiration policies it is very difficult to remember all the passwords. So I want to do a script that connects to each domain with my user account in that domain and changes the password. I'll repeat that for all the domains.

Comment: Have you looked into the [Set-ADAccountPassword](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617261.aspx) cmdlet?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have the Active Directory PowerShell Module installed, this is a pretty easy task using Set-ADAccountPassword.

You can use the -Server parameter to supply a different Domain Controller name from each Domain to set the password on that Domain.

```
$DomainControllers = "Domain1DC","Domain2DC","Domain3DC"
$MyName = "MyUserName"
ForEach ($DomainController In $DomainControllers) {
    Set-AdAccountPassword -Identity $MyName -Server $DomainController
}
```

Set-ADUserAccountPassword used this way will prompt you for the old password then the new password for each domain controller.

Comment: It shouldn't.  Since it will prompt for the current password of the user account, that should be all the rights it needs to perform the password change.

Comment: simple one by one:
`Set-AdAccountPassword -Identity AnyDomainUserId`
no need to run powershell by the user you want to change
Also quick info how to import PS of AD:  
`import-module activedirectory`

Comment: how to install the AD PS module: check `Get-WindowsFeature RSAT-AD* | FT -a`  and install via `Install-WindowsFeature RSAT-ADDS`